# iPhone application, Documents directory on Mac

Tags: iphone

I'm reading through some of the documentation about File Management on iOS.  When you create an application for the simulator, does the application get created somewhere on my hard drive?  If so, where is it?

Also, does this have access to the Documents directory?  Like if I create some test .txt file, and want to see it in the App->Documents folder, is that possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Look here:

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications

Change the 4.3.2 to be the version of the Simulator you are using.

Within that folder you will find your apps, except the they are named cryptically.  Open one of those folders and you will find your app, named as you recognize it, and the Documents, Library and tmp folders.  Documents is where you find the docs that your app creates and uses.    You can, in fact, makes changes to the files in the Documents folder or just access their content to see what your app sees or writes.

Comment: With Lion, the ~/Library/ is hidden.  Use cmd-G to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Under XCode 6, the document directory for your app is quite hidden:

~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Containers/Data/Application//

You can find the directory for your app with this command:

```
$ sudo find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices -name <APP_NAME>.app | grep -o '.*/'
```